# Downloading a Zapier Project to Local Directory and Adding Custom Fields to Trigger

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'm currently working on a production project on Zapier and I need to download it to my local directory to implement some modifications. I've already generated a deploy key and logged in using zapier **login --sso**.

Despite reviewing the documentation, I'm uncertain about the correct procedure for pulling the project from the Zapier server to my local directory. While the "**zapier link**" command is mentioned, it doesn't seem to address my specific requirements.

Could someone provide guidance on how to safely download the project without causing any disruptions to the production environment?

Additionally, due to the production status of the project, I'm unable to test different Zapier commands.

Furthermore, I'm interested in adding custom fields to a trigger via the UI in the Zapier dashboard at "https://developer.zapier.com". However, when attempting to do so, a popup message appears stating, "**This version was created by the CLI and can only be modified there.**"

Specifically, I need to add the following fields to the trigger:

```
const getProduct = (z, bundle) => {
const product = {
    id: bundle.cleanedRequest.id,
    name: bundle.cleanedRequest.name,
    first_field: bundle.cleanedRequest.name, // Custom field to be added
    second_field: bundle.cleanedRequest.name, // Custom field to be added
    // Other existing fields...
};
```

Any insights, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions on achieving these tasks would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer:
[Zapier community](https://community.zapier.com/general-discussion-13/download-existing-cli-converted-project-after-push-11011)